# Regular expressions (ab*foo) vs (a.*foo) difference?

Tags: regex

From this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) I learned about "Regular Expressions - Quantifiers", and based on this [test code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/test_harness.html) used in this tutorial.

I have a question on these tests:

```
Enter your regex: ab*foo
Enter input string to search: xabfooxxxabbbfoox
I found the text "abfoo" starting at index 1 and ending at index 6.
I found the text "abbbfoo" starting at index 9 and ending at index 16.
```

But

```
Enter your regex: a.*foo
Enter input string to search: xabfooxxxabbbfoox
I found the text "abfooxxxabbbfoo" starting at index 1 and ending at index 16.
```

Why Not these:

```
I found the text "abfoo" starting at index 1 and ending at index 6.
I found the text "abbbfoo" starting at index 9 and ending at index 16.
```

In general I noteiced that whenever `.*` or `.+` used:

- There is only a single match if any.
- The matched section of the string is always the longest one.

So how Matching work for each?

Answer (score 3):

`ab*foo` will match an `a`, followed by 0 or more `b`s, followed by `foo`

`a.*foo` will match an `a`, followed by 0 or more of any character (which is represented by `.`), followed by `foo`

`b+` would match 1 or more instances of the character `b`

Check out [regex101](http://regex101.com/) for a nice regex testing tool that will explain what your pattern means

Comment: Did you read the "last" line of the question? It's not really asking a general purpose of `.*` and `b*` he's asking why it's not working as intended when he tests with those 2 regex.

Answer (score 2):

You have the problem that in the second regex, `*` is a greedy quantifier. What does that mean? That means that it won't stop until the LAST occurence of that `foo` string.

You can make it to be non-greedy just by adding `?` after the quantifier, that will tell the regex to match as less as possible so it will match what you want.

After all:

Your first one will match as many `b` as possible, even 0
Your second one will match as many `.` (a whatever char) as possible, even 0.

Answer (score 1):

`*` greedily matches zero or more of the previous character.  `.` matches any character.  So `.*` means "match zero or more of any character".

The key is the "greedily" part.  `a.*foo` will continue searching all the way to the end of the string looking for the final occurrence of `foo`, once it finds it, it "backs up" and marks the match complete.  So, if you have `axxxxfooxxxfooxxx`, the greedy matching behavior will match the middle `foo`, treating those like any other characters, but will stop at the last one.

Answer (score 0):

`acfoo` matches `a.*foo` but not `ab.*foo`, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

.* or .+ produce one match if any, because by default, most regex programs set to match the longest substring possible.

Some may be configurable through options, though.

Answer (score 0):

### `ab*foo`

Will match a followed by 0 or more b and foo
For example:

```
afoo
abfoo
abbfoo
abbbfoo
abbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbfoo
```

### `a.*foo`

Will match a followed by anything followed by foo

```
afoo
abfoo
acfoo
adfoo
asdfoo
asdasdfasdfawqfefoo
```